# vi remove double quotes only processes current line

Tags: vi, substitution

I would like to remove all double quotes from a text file using **vi**.
My first approach was to use the substitute function as follows

```
:s/\"//g
```

This is working, but only on the current line.
The docs says "g" makes the substitution global

**How can I extend the substitution to the whole file?**

Comment: By using % (shorthand for 1,$ ) as the selection `:%s/\"//g`

Comment: Bingo. Please post this as a response to get full credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `g` (*global*) suffix in the context regular expression substitution
refers *all* matches for that **line**. This usage dates back to the time
when editors were line-oriented. Vi is simply the visual mode of `ex`
which Bill Joy wrote as a replacement for the venerable,
[ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29).

When running `ex` commands, using the percentage sign, `%` as the *range*
for the command is equivalent to specifying `1,$`, i.e., the entire file.

*Note: When earlier today, I saw this question's title and with no answers, I figured I'd most likely know the answer. However, after clicking on it, I saw it had already been answered in the comments and thought that it'd only be fair to wait a few (4) hours before posting the above answer.*